# Maya script rigging control direction problem

Tags: maya

As image shows here, i use node editor connect a customed attribute to the rotateZ of three different controls. All thoses control have a right direction.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgHLC.png)

But when i use cmds.connectAttr('wrist_ctr.fist','thump_x_ctr.rotateZ',force=True) to conenct, those three controls direction is totally wrong.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRYsO.png)

I've tried so many methods but still not solve this issue, anyone could help me would be very very thanksful!

I want to get a solution for my problem.